# Copy records from one table to another symmetric table except the auto increment IDENTITY field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two symmetric tables Table1 & Table2, ID is the field defined as IDENTITY field for auto increment, I am trying to copy the records from Table1 to Table2 with the below query,

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] 
SELECT 
(
    SELECT c.name 
    FROM sys.tables AS t 
      INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo' 
      AND t.name = 'Table2' AND c.name !='ID'
) FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

I am getting below error,

**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

Am I missing anything???

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work like this, you'd have to use dynamic SQL to get this to work. Stop being lazy, and type out/copy and paste in the column names. Alternatively, drag and drop the column names from the list in SSMS. You should also be specifying the destination columns in the INSERT part of your statement too - otherwise it'll try and insert by ordinal position, which will probably be wrong.

Comment: Your subquery just returns a list of column names - strings - and tries to insert that set into only the first column of your table. I agree with @Bridge - stop being lazy and construct proper insert statements with explicit column lists on both sides.

Comment: Actually table Schema is not in our control, tables will be created dynamically, so I need to copy records from one table to another by reading the schema, how to do that with out reading columns as cumulative string and parsing them?

Comment: That doesn't sound like fun! If you need to copy a table you know nothing about directly, does it need to be created in advance or maintained/updated later? If not, how about the syntax `SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM OldTable` - no need to type out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically create query for insert/select you have to use dynamic sql and string concatenation using `STUFF..FOR XML` construct:

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = 
    STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + name 
            FROM sys.columns 
                    WHERE object_id = object_id('Table2') 
                       AND name <> 'ID'
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] (' + @cols + ') 
               SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM [dbo].[Table1]'

EXEC (@sql)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10301/1)**